# Why data.matrix doen't convert data.frame properly?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, double

I'm a newbie with R and I don't understand why I can't get a numeric matrix from data.frame with data.matrix. I create a data.frame cbinding some lists. When I need to convert it to a matrix to do some calculus, it can't because variable isn't a numeric...

medias_1, simetrias_1, medias_5 and simetrias_5 are lists of double.

```
> datos_1 <- data.frame(cbind(Medias = medias_1, Simetrias = simetrias_1, Etiqueta = 1))
> datos_5 <- data.frame(cbind(Medias = medias_5, Simetrias = simetrias_5, Etiqueta = -1))

> datos <- rbind(datos_1, datos_5)

> muestras <- cbind(datos$Medias, datos$Simetrias)

> h <- head(muestras,3)
> h
     [,1]      [,2]   
[1,] 0.876957  -9.356 
[2,] 0.8861406 -12.598
[3,] 0.8846289 -8.224 
> typeof(h)
[1] "list"
> typeof(data.matrix(h))
[1] "list"
> typeof(as.matrix(h))
[1] "list"
```

What's the problem? I can't understand it.

SOLUTION: Remove cbind inside data.frame()! I've to convert lists to numeric but it hasn't any problem.

Comment: Try just doing `data.frame()` rather than `data.frame(cbind())`. (And please, never do `data.frame(cbind())` ever again!)

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem :)!!